# Does angular *ngFor directive needs trackBy anymore?

Tags: angular

app.component.html File:

```
<button (click)="update()">Add More</button>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of persons; trackBy: trackFn">
    {{ "Name:- " + person.name + " || Age:- " + person.age }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts File:

```
export class AppComponent {
  persons = [
    {
      name: "Huzaifa",
      age: 16
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 28
    },
    {
      name: "Kerma",
      age: 22
    }
  ];

  update() {
    this.persons.push({
      name: "umair",
      age: 20
    });
  }
}
```

When I was learning angular 7, I noticed that I have to use trackBy to track items while updating data..Else angular was updating entire DOM on which ngForOf directive was applied..We was able to see that by pink highlight from the chrome's developer tool

BUT

Now I am not facing this issue even without using trackBy function!

Have you noticed that ?

Help me

And also please don't report me If did something wrong while asking the question...Just tell me my mistake and I will try my best to improve that..

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: <button (click)="update()">Add More</button>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of persons">
    {{ "Name:- " + person.name + " || Age:- " + person.age }}
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: export class AppComponent {
  persons = [
    {
      name: "Huzaifa",
      age: 16
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 28
    },
    {
      name: "Kerma",
      age: 22
    }
  ];

  update() {
    this.persons.push({
      name: "umair",
      age: 20
    });
  }
}

Comment: Sir first comment is the app.component.html while the other comment is the app.component.ts file..I mean a part of that fie associated with this misconception

Answer (score 0):

i tried it with angular 7 for data coming from HTTP request, without the trackBy angular was updating the whole thing

Comment: yes sir I also faced this in angular 7 but in angular 8, I am not facing this anymore.... May be its my browser problem or my miss-observation

Comment: are you talking about angular 7 or 8?